# ¿Por qué se sigue ejecutando el contador del fragment anterior?

Tags: android, android-studio, contador, viewmodel

Hola en la siguiente aplicación: https://github.com/Miguel546/proyectoandroid

Tengo una actividad y tres fragmentos que están vivos.

En el FragmentUno el viewModel está atado al Fragment:

```
class UnoFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var unoBinding: FragmentUnoBinding
    private val unoViewModel: UnoViewModel by viewModels()
```

En el FragmentDos el viewModel está atado al Fragment:

```
class DosFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var dosBinding: FragmentDosBinding
    private val dosViewModel: DosViewModel by viewModels()
```

En el fragment tres también el viewmodel está atado al fragment:

```
class TresFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var tresBinding: FragmentTresBinding
    private val tresViewModel: TresViewModel by viewModels()
```

En el fragment uno:

Está un contador que se actualiza por medio de la función actualizarContadorUno() que cuenta en un while, la función se inicializa en el init del ViewModel, la misma función está en el fragmentDos y el fragmentTres.

```
init{
        actualizarContadorUno()
    }

fun actualizarContadorUno(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            while(true){
                delay(1000)
                _contador.value = _contador.value + 1
                Log.i("tag", "tag fragment uno ${contador.value}")
            }
        }
    }
```

En la pantalla se actualiza el contador mediante la llamada a la función collect del flow contador.

```
private fun initObservers() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
                launch {
                    unoViewModel.contador.collect{
                        unoBinding.contador.text = "Contador Fragment Uno\n$it"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Cuando le doy click para al botón para ir del fragmentUno al fragmentDos, el log sigue pintando lo del fragmentUno igual sucede cuando vas del fragment dos al fragment tres. En teoría cuando pasas de un fragment a otro el ViewModel muere, entonces la corroutina también moriría porque se sigue pintando los logs del fragment uno y del fragment dos cuando estás en el fragment 3.

Pero cuando retrocedo del fragmentTres al fragmentDos el log del fragmentTres se elimina y cuando regreso del fragmentDos al fragmentUno el log del fragment dos elimina.

¿Porqué cuando avanzo no se eliminan los logs y cuando retrocedo si se eliminan los logs, y también cuando estoy en el fragmentUno, le doy atrás y salgo de la aplicación el log del fragmentUno sigue ejecutándose?

Aquí dejo los logs cuando estoy en el fragmento 3:

```
2023-11-26 19:58:14.470 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment tres 1
2023-11-26 19:58:14.826 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment uno 11
2023-11-26 19:58:14.901 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment dos 6
2023-11-26 19:58:15.475 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment tres 2
2023-11-26 19:58:15.828 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment uno 12
2023-11-26 19:58:15.905 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment dos 7
2023-11-26 19:58:16.480 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment tres 3
2023-11-26 19:58:16.830 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment uno 13
2023-11-26 19:58:16.910 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment dos 8
2023-11-26 19:58:17.485 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment tres 4
2023-11-26 19:58:17.832 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment uno 14
2023-11-26 19:58:17.915 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment dos 9
2023-11-26 19:58:18.491 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment tres 5
2023-11-26 19:58:18.834 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment uno 15
2023-11-26 19:58:18.920 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment dos 10
2023-11-26 19:58:19.496 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment tres 6
2023-11-26 19:58:19.835 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment uno 16
2023-11-26 19:58:19.924 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment dos 11
2023-11-26 19:58:20.501 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment tres 7
2023-11-26 19:58:20.836 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment uno 17
2023-11-26 19:58:20.929 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment dos 12
2023-11-26 19:58:21.507 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment tres 8
2023-11-26 19:58:21.838 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment uno 18
2023-11-26 19:58:21.933 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment dos 13
2023-11-26 19:58:22.512 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment tres 9
2023-11-26 19:58:22.840 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment uno 19
2023-11-26 19:58:22.938 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment dos 14
2023-11-26 19:58:23.518 11183-11183 tag                     com.ejemplo.proyecto                 I  tag fragment tres 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Por ahi tienes unos errorcitos con la parte del ciclo de vida:

- El viewModel no muere (Ósea esta bien que no muera, es parte de su naturaleza, solo tómalo en cuenta).
- Debes usar el método onPause, justo para pausar tu contador en cada fragmento.

En tus fragments tendrías algo así:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class UnoFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var unoBinding: FragmentUnoBinding
    private val unoViewModel: UnoViewModel by viewModels()

    private var contadorJob: Job? = null // Variable para almacenar el Job de la coroutine
    
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        unoBinding = FragmentUnoBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return unoBinding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        unoBinding.btnIrAFDos.setOnClickListener {
            contadorJob?.cancel()
            findNavController().navigate(UnoFragmentDirections.actionUnoFragmentToDosFragment())
        }
        initObservers()
    }

    private fun initObservers() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                unoViewModel.contador.collect {
                    unoBinding.contador.text = "Contador Fragment Uno\n$it"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        unoViewModel.startContador()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        unoViewModel.stopContador()
    }
}
```

Y en tus viewModels, algo tal que asi:

```
@HiltViewModel
class UnoViewModel @Inject constructor(): ViewModel() {
    private val _contador = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val contador: StateFlow<Int> = _contador
    private var contadorJob: Job? = null

    fun startContador() {
        contadorJob?.cancel() // Cancela el contador existente, si lo hay
        contadorJob = viewModelScope.launch {
            while (true) {
                delay(1000)
                _contador.value += 1
                Log.i("tag1", "tag fragment 1 ${contador.value}")
            }
        }
    }

    fun stopContador() {
        contadorJob?.cancel()
    }
}
```

Es buena idea darle la responsabilidad a un job de coordinar tu contador.

https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines/coroutines-adv?hl=es-419#job

Comment: ¿Porque el ViewModel no muere cuando se cambia de fragmento en fragmento? porque está con la clase import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels --> private val unoViewModel: UnoViewModel by viewModels(), en teoría debería morir.